# How to convert dynamo items from scan to dict/json?

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto

I am using boto to retrieve dynamo Items from a scan.

```
for item in scan_results:
    print item
```

I can access each property with:

```
for item in scan_results:
    print item['propA']

for item in scan_results:
    print json.dumps(item) # This does not work
```

How do I convert each item to a json object or a dict?
I want to avoid having to iterate over the keys in item and generating a dict through loops if i can avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

`for item in scan_results:
    print json.dumps(dict(item))`